# How to create multiple log instances?

Tags: logging, rust

I'm developing a project that depends on a library which is a kind of telemetry service, using `log4rs` as logger for recording report info. The project self use `env_logger` as the log instrument. When initializing the logger, the process failed due to `SetLogger` being called twice in `log`, the common underlying lib of both `log4rs` and `env_logger`:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on `Err` value: SetLoggerError(())', /usr/local/cargo/git/checkouts/zhiyan-monitor-273ad973f6dcd2df/9140485/src...
```

I found the `STATE` in `log` is a global variable. It seems impossible to enable both `env_logger` and `log4rs`. Is there any elegant way to create multiple log instances?

Comment: If they were both under your control and initialized in one place, you could make your own composite `Log` implementation that used both, but it sounds like they are set up separately. But if so, that is poor design for a library to install itself as a global resource - usually that is left up to the top level binary to decide.

Comment: Do you really need both logging methods? And if so, can you configure the log4js one to output logs similarly to env-logger? Log4js is designed to be pretty all-encompassing and customizable.

Comment: The main issue is that the telemetry library is a background service, it will initialize the `log4rs` according to its own configuration automatically. I can skip initializing the `env_logger` in my project, but this way will mix two kind of log, which is not maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own logger that forwards to two loggers, it's simple:

```rust
use log::Log;

pub struct CombineLogger<L1, L2>(pub L1, pub L2);

impl<L1: Log, L2: Log> Log for CombineLogger<L1, L2> {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &log::Metadata<'_>) -> bool {
        self.0.enabled(metadata) || self.1.enabled(metadata)
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &log::Record<'_>) {
        self.0.log(record);
        self.1.log(record);
    }

    fn flush(&self) {
        self.0.flush();
        self.1.flush();
    }
}

pub fn set_two_loggers(log4rs: log4rs::Logger, env_logger: env_logger::Logger) {
    log::set_boxed_logger(Box::new(CombineLogger(log4rs, env_logger)))
        .expect("logging already initialized");
}
```